# Overriding DataPointStyle in a WPF Toolkit Chart

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I'd like to override the `DataPointStyle` of the `LineSeries` in my WPF Toolkit `Chart`:

```
<chart:LineSeries>
    <chart:DataPointSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <Style
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type chart:LineDataPoint}}"
            TargetType="{x:Type chart:LineDataPoint}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </chart:DataPointSeries.DataPointStyle>
</chart:LineSeries>
```

However when I do this I lose the automatic palette coloring where each series has a different color. Applying a `DataPointStyle` causes them all to turn orange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until someone suggests a better method, I've manually set the colors. I guess I won't be using the automatic palette for now.

```
<Style
    x:Key="SimpleDataPointStyle"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}}"
    TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
</Style>

...

<chart:LineSeries ... >
    <chart:DataPointSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <Style
            BasedOn="{StaticResource SimpleDataPointStyle}"
            TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </chart:DataPointSeries.DataPointStyle>
</chart:LineSeries>
<chart:LineSeries ... >
    <chart:DataPointSeries.DataPointStyle>
        <Style
            BasedOn="{StaticResource SimpleDataPointStyle}"
            TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </chart:DataPointSeries.DataPointStyle>
</chart:LineSeries>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those interested this can also be done in the code behind that adds a new LineSeries as follows:

```
ResourceDictionary rd = MyChart.Palette[MyChart.Series.Count % MyChart.Palette.Count];
Style style = new Style(typeof(LineDataPoint), rd["DataPointStyle"] as Style);
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(OpacityProperty, 0.0));

LineSeries ls = new LineSeries()
{
    DataPointStyle = style
};
MyChart.Series.Add(ls);
```

Comment: if you want to get the Color of each background serie :

ResourceDictionary rd = mcLineChart.Palette[mcLineChart.Series.Count % mcLineChart.Palette.Count];
            var myBrush = rd["Background"] as Brush;
...
 SetStyleProperty(sty, Control.BackgroundProperty, myBrush);

Answer (score -2):

instead of `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />`
just bind the value to color as a property of the model. So `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Color}" />`