# disable wpftoolkit chart datapoint

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, charts

Does anybody know how to turn off the datapoints for a noraml LineSeries in a WPFToolkit chart?  I find them to be very annoying, and not useful to my purposes, but I can't find a simple property or anything like that on the class itself.

Comment: When creating `LineSeries` from code, it is posible to use solution from this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11358310/885854, to remove datapoint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing (collapsing) DataPoints in a LineSeries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205913/removing-collapsing-datapoints-in-a-lineseries)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want to hide them?

It is possible if to set the empty `ControlTemplate` to the `Template` property.
Here is the example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="InvisibleDataPoint" TargetType="{x:Type charting:DataPoint}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <charting:Chart>
        <charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ChartItems}" IndependentValuePath="XValue" DependentValuePath="YValue" 
                                 DataPointStyle="{StaticResource InvisibleDataPoint}"/>
    </charting:Chart>
</Grid>
```

And although the points are invisible, you can set other properties, like `Background` and change the look of chart.

[image]

Comment: Umm.. no, that doesn't work.  Seems to only change the color of the points.

Comment: Seems that this guy is getting the same problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042488/overriding-datapointstyle-in-a-wpf-toolkit-chart  However, I can't set the style even manually.  All I get is orange.

Comment: @A.R. Maybe my explanation isn't easy to reproduce or I haven't understood the question correctly. I've attached the screenshot of my chart wich doesn't have datapoints. If you meant something different - upload an image of a correct chart.

Comment: No, that is the result that I want, I'm just not getting it on my end.  Maybe this is a version problem.  If I do a direct cut and paste of your code I still get a bunch of Orange dots.  Sorry for the confusion, I'll look into this over the weekend and hopefully get to the bottom of it.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: OK, so I win the bonehead award.  I had a line of code that was setting 'DataPointStyle = null' and that was causing the problem.  Just some leftover junk from experimenting, so.....