# wpf toolkit chart LineSeries DataPointStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, charts

I want to add `LineSeries` without points just lines. I want to do this dynamically from code not xaml.

I tried to do this with following code:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(LineDataPoint));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.VisibilityProperty,Visibility.Hidden));

var series = new LineSeries()
{
    Title = name,
    DependentValuePath = "Y",
    IndependentValuePath = "X",
    ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<FloatingPoint>(),
    DataPointStyle = style,
};

chart.Series.Add(series);
```

However it doesn't work; I still see the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355425/disable-wpftoolkit-chart-datapoint/5356109#5356109).

Briefly: the `Visibility` property won't work, you should set the `Template` property to null.

Corrected lines:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(LineDataPoint));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.TemplateProperty, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide the data points set width and height to 0 of the same.

```
  style.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.WidthProperty, 0.0));
  style.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.HeightProperty, 0.0));
```